# Listagg Redshift DDL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to retrieve the DDL for a table in Redshift. I found [this](https://discourse.snowplowanalytics.com/t/generating-redshift-ddl-create-statements-for-tables-that-already-exist/556) view where I can easily select the definition for any table. However I need this information in one line, and I know that there is this Listagg function, but if I try to do this:

```
select listagg(ddl, ' ')
from admin.v_generate_tbl_ddl
where schemaname = 'schema'
and tablename = 'orders'
```

It's giving me this error:

> Query execution failed
>
> Reason: SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: One or more of the used functions
>   must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user
>   table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, etc

Can You please help me on how can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know anout Redshift, but try nesting in a Derived Table/Common Table Expression: `with cte as (select ddl
from admin.v_generate_tbl_ddl
where schemaname = 'schema'
and tablename = 'orders') select listagg(ddl, ' ') from cte`

Comment: It is giving me the same error message.

Answer (score 7):

`listagg` function is a *compute-node only* function.

But the query you run to get the table ddl runs only on leader because it only specifies pg_* tables.

According to AWS documentation

*A query that references only catalog tables (tables with a PG prefix, such as PG_TABLE_DEF) or that does not reference any tables, runs exclusively on the leader node.*

*If a query that uses a compute-node function doesn't reference a user-defined table or Amazon Redshift system table returns the following error.*

***[Amazon] (500310) Invalid operation: One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created table.***

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions_compute_node_only.html

To sum up, since your query does not reference any **user created table**, you can not use `listagg`