# Redshift join each values in an array

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I have a table like below (its actually the `pg_group` table)

```
group_id | group_name | userid
_____________________________________
101      | gr1        | {100,101}
102      | gr2        | {100,110,120}
```

I have another table where I can see the name of the user id.

```
userid  | username
______________________
100     | user1
101     | user2
110     | user3
120     | user4
```

I want to join these 2 tables and generate the output like this.

```
group_id | group_name | username
_____________________________________
101      | gr1        | user1,user2
102      | gr2        | user1,user3,user4
```

I tried `listagg` and etc, but it didn't work as expected.

#### Update:

I tried this one, but list agg seems not working.

```
SELECT   I.group_name, listagg(J.username,',') 
FROM pg_group I 
LEFT JOIN pg_user J 
ON J.userid = ANY(I.userid) 
GROUP BY I.group_name  



ERROR: One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, etc;
```

Comment: Updated the question, For now its for RedShift

Comment: What's the data type of userid column?

Comment: its an integer column

Comment: For pg_group table?

Comment: Please look into this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910777/listagg-redshift-ddl/54911839

Comment: I have changed my answer. Please let me know if it helpd.

Answer (score 0):

Here first I have converted arrays of user_ID INTO ROWS WITH UNNEST THEN COLLECTED username against those user_id and at last with string_agg() function again those usernames have been grouped into a comma separated column.

```
select group_id,group_name,string_agg(username,',')usrname from
(select group_id,group_name,unnest(userid::text[])user_id  from pg_group )pg 
inner join pg_user u
on pg.user_id::int = u.userid
group by group_id,group_name
```

Answer (score 0):

From googling so far I have understood that you cannot use listagg() if there is no user defined table is involved. I have found a way around. But I cannot check it since I don't have Redshift platform. Please check it out:

```
select group_name,listagg(username, ', ') within group (order by column_name)
from
(
    SELECT   I.group_name,J.username
    FROM pg_group I 
    LEFT JOIN pg_user J 
    ON J.userid = ANY(I.userid) 
    left join (select top 1 1 from my_schema.my_table)
    on 1=1
)
```

Instead of **my_schema.my_table** Please use any of your user defined table

Comment: actually in RedShift, string_agg wont support

Comment: Extremely sorry. I thought it supports postgresql function. Let me find a way then.